# Typescript generic indexed access type of rest parameters

Tags: typescript-generics, typescript-types, rest-parameters

**I am stuck here:**

I have an interface `Field` which has a name and a value of some unknown type.

```
interface Field<T> {
    name: string;
    value: T;
}
```

I then have a function `form`, which takes any amount of `Field`'s as rest parameters and returns the data they hold.

```
function form<T extends Field<unknown>[]>(
    ...fields: T
): { [k in T[number]['name']]: T[number]['value'] } {
    let data = {};
    fields.forEach((field) => (data[field.name] = field.value));
    return <{ [k in T[number]['name']]: T[number]['value'] }>data;
}
```

It look like this is action:

```
const age: Field<number> = { name: 'age', value: 30 };
const sex: Field<string> = { name: 'sex', value: 'men' };

const data = form(age, sex);
// { age: 30, sex: 'men' }
```

In this example the types of `age` and `sex` are just the union of all fields.

```
data.age; // number | string
data.sex; // number | string
```

What i want is data to be of type:

```
const data: { age: number, sex: string } = form(age, sex);
```

But this returns the error `ts(2451)`.

What does the return type of `form` need to be.
Is this even possible?

*(I'm using typescript version 4.9.3, the latest as of 2022-11-29)*

[Edit 2022-11-30]: add Link to working example

[typescriptlang.org/play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYB4AqAfMgN4CwAUMtciHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDclNyAG5xMAV2bJ8fCgF9KlGKJAIwwAPYhkMNVHoAKAHRGYGHKxboseJQGsQagO4hCAbQC6ASlL8amCGGRsODA4FhJkFxsWdk4QLjcWOBAAT2QZZABeUhlpARMrVgNtKABRRAALPT18nC8M4j0gkJca7AM6RjdMrVM24TEIDw9cmih-UShNJrhpOQpKBA12ZDguCUscXBBRegAjaGIs8I6JAHJViFOAGiERcRYAZgAGNOlFkGXWCAAPC17cGLcQ6kWgMM5fb7XW4DFinRggU6veQUd7LabdYr6C43CHDBZLNR+AyYNRcPRgZIABwgahggWCcAM2OQFOptPpIQMuJ4yAA9LzkAAibZ7aCCm6CwFxQWUIA)

Comment: Please provide a working example as a link to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Field` should have a ganegic on its `name` also

```
interface Field<K extends string, V> {
  name: K;
  value: V;
}

function ensureField<K extends string, V>(field: Field<K, V>) {
  return field;
}

type FieldListToRecord<List extends Field<any, any>[], O extends {} = {}> =
  | List extends [infer F extends Field<any, any>, ...infer L extends Field<any, any>[]] ?
  FieldListToRecord<L, O & (
    F extends Field<infer K, infer V> ? { [k in K]: V }
    : never
  )>
  : { [K in keyof O]: O[K] }; // <- Pure<T>


function form<T extends Field<any, any>[]>(
  ...fields: T
): FieldListToRecord<T> {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    fields.map(({ name, value }) => [name, value])
  );
}

const age = ensureField({ name: 'age', value: 30 });
//    ^?
const sex = ensureField({ name: 'sex', value: 'men' });
//    ^?

const data = form(age, sex);
//    ^?
// { age: 30, sex: 'men' }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGLAgGwCYB4DSyEAHpCNgM7IVhSgDmANMgGoB8yA3gFDLIhwAthABcyfAG5eyAG5xMAV1GspAX27cYCkAjDAA9iCIgKCqBHRY8hEmUrVaDZuwAUMDDjGWcBZ2wCUXNLmYGZG7lZqGmAAngAOKN7YADLANAAq%20gBKEAj6UHipNESkEORUSbhwIDHM1TFsANoAuswA8iV2VJyqyAC8XKocfdIAPshFYJ1l9o2gMNBo0%20VoHnj1dTVszAB0e-OLycv2lRvI9U3NzcgA-NJJk5k5eQW4ye3IAGTILtJ8qMcKmtcAcoOJmKDWBwblxkI0ANbIUDiZpiFjIdR8PhiEAQGTQaT%20NjSMScOGEZHwiAxfQwZBtVH0xr4a6qCTIAD0HOQuAAtMgAApmCC4dLEjRaHR6QzIGD5QSiwGrKxVGqbBotNi-Ph7HYRHAUMTpbj%20LxrR7ZXL5PBioJ8EJhekAIwAVrkwHqoPpBABRcB0CAUbVY-WUHaCOBxFwuMkCYTMOSKFCqQJ9DiNOMQBPyJTNfyEqLcPImKZwegoAZlUzmJIx-hCZQAcjLEEb2aTYgAzAAGDH%20KRcrHIAB6d2LxQoJH6xmrFjWdczYkbk%20IbdkOabwhAjb7A%205WNHGnHU2wcDAcGncqgghcLeYK-73EHB7ug7JLa73fvJCXW536iAA)

Comment: You are my hero! I learned a lot just from your code, thanks!!